# What is the rank of the linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T: M_{{2},{7}}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathscr{F}$ be a linear transformation
and suppose a non-zero matrix $B \in M_{{2},{7}}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $Ker(T)=Span(B)$. What is $rank(T)$?

Comment: What is the dimension of $\operatorname{ker}(T)$?

Comment: What is $\mathscr{F}$?

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the rank-nullity theorem since $M_{2,7}(\mathbb{R})$ is finite-dimensional.

We have $$dim(Ker(T))+rank(T)=dim(M_{2,7}(\mathbb{R}))=14$$

Since $B$ is non-zero, we know that $dim(span(B))=1=dim(Ker(T))$, hence $$rank(T)=14-1=13$$